# How can you get battery usage by app in Windows using PowerShell?

Tags: windows

You can get battery usage using `powercfg /batteryreport`, but this doesn't show battery usage by app like in Battery Usage in the following image.

How can you get battery usage by app using PowerShell?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

No, you can’t do this using PowerShell.

Answer (score 2):

To get Battery usage by application in Windows using powershell, you can use the script which retrieves battery usage information for each running application and displays it in descending order of battery consumption.

```
# get the battery usage by app

# get the list of running processes
$processes = Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "name <> 'Idle'" | Select-Object ProcessID, Name

#  initialize a hashtable to store the battery usage for each app
$batteryUsage = @{}

#loop through  each running process
foreach ($process in $processes) {
    $processID = $process.ProcessID
    $processName = $process.Name

    # Get the battery usage information for the process
    $powerInformation = Get-WmiObject -Namespace root\cimv2\power -Class Win32_ProcessPowerUsage | Where-Object { $_.ProcessID -eq $processID }

    # If battery usage information is available
    if ($powerInformation) {
        $batteryUsage[$processName] = $powerInformation.ElapsedTime
    }
}

#sort the hashtable by battery usage in descending order
$sortedBatteryUsage = $batteryUsage.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object -Property Value -Descending

# Display the battery usage by app
foreach ($entry in $sortedBatteryUsage) {
    $appName = $entry.Name
    $batteryTime = $entry.Value / 10000000  # Convert the elapsed time to seconds
    Write-Host "$appName: $batteryTime seconds"
}
```

this script retrieves battery usage information using WMI.

Comment: Did you test your code in windows 11?